# Can't sort a linked list

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to sort a list in ascending order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct city {
    char ISO[3];
    char name[20];
    unsigned long inhabitants;
};
typedef struct city City;

struct listnode {
    City thecity;
    struct listnode *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct listnode ListNode;


ListNode *sortForInhabitants(ListNode *, size_t );

int main(){
    /* stuff to initialize list */


    ListNode sortedlist = *sortForInhabitants(&startPtr,num_elem);


    /* printf the output */
}


ListNode *sortForInhabitants(ListNode *sPtr, size_t num_nodes){
    ListNode *newsortedlist = NULL;
    ListNode *prevsortedPtr;
    ListNode *prevUNsortedPtr = sPtr;
    ListNode *exchangePtr;
    ListNode *currUNsortedPtr = sPtr;
    ListNode *tempPtr;
    for (size_t i=1; i<=num_nodes; ++i){
        exchangePtr = prevUNsortedPtr;
        for (size_t i=1; i<=num_nodes; ++i){
            if (exchangePtr->thecity.inhabitants > currUNsortedPtr->thecity.inhabitants){
                tempPtr = exchangePtr;
                exchangePtr = currUNsortedPtr;
                currUNsortedPtr = tempPtr;
            }
        }
        prevUNsortedPtr = prevUNsortedPtr->nextPtr;

        if (newsortedlist==NULL){
            ListNode *newsortlinkPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
            if (newsortlinkPtr){
                newsortlinkPtr->thecity.inhabitants = exchangePtr->thecity.inhabitants;
                newsortlinkPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
                newsortedlist = newsortlinkPtr;
                prevsortedPtr = newsortlinkPtr;
            } else {
                printf("\nNo memory.\n");
            }
        } else {
            ListNode *newsortlinkPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
            if (newsortlinkPtr){
                newsortlinkPtr->thecity.inhabitants = exchangePtr->thecity.inhabitants;
                newsortlinkPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
                prevsortedPtr->nextPtr = newsortlinkPtr;
                prevsortedPtr = newsortlinkPtr;
            } else {
                printf("\nNo memory.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return newsortedlist;
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted list:
PA Palermo 673735
ME Messina 236962
CT Catania 313396
TP Trapani 68528
AG Agrigento 59605
RG Ragusa 73500

Sorted list:
  673735
  236962
  313396
  68528
  59605
  73500
```

Why? It took me a long time but I don't see the effects of the effort.

Also, I'd like to know if it is adviceable to create a new ListNode (like I'm doing in this sorting function) or to just "adjusts" the previous ListNode just using pointers... What would be better?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: How do you print the output? Maybe the sorting works and the printing is wrong?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the print function is the same either for unsorted and for sorted list, so I guess it isn't the printf that makes problems.

Comment: You also guessed that the rest of the program works correctly but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you were implementing the selection sort algorithm. Your secondary loop had a very obvious bug which you missed.

```
ListNode *sortForInhabitants(ListNode *sPtr, size_t num_nodes){

  // initial code

  // this loop is for finding the i_th smallest element
  for (size_t i=1; i<=num_nodes; ++i){
    exchangePtr = prevUNsortedPtr;

    // your second loop is wrong. Correct access of the loop is given below.
    // as you have already found (i-1) smallest elements, you are now going
    // to search through the rest of the linked list.
    for (size_t j=i+1; j<=num_nodes; ++j){
      if (exchangePtr->thecity.inhabitants > currUNsortedPtr->thecity.inhabitants){
        tempPtr = exchangePtr;
        exchangePtr = currUNsortedPtr;
        currUNsortedPtr = tempPtr;
    }
  // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you actually *explained* what the bug was and how it can be fixed, instead of just showing the code (it is not clear to me if the code you have shown is the original code or the fixed code).